# Add prefix to auto-generated table names in Spring-Boot Entity annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have some entities in my project. For example:

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
...
```

I know I can change the auto-generated name of an entity using the `name` property:

```
@Entity(name = "groups")
```

But my question is how could I add a `prefix` to auto-generated names of entities, for example, something like:

```
@Entity(prefix = "pro_")
```

**If there is no way like that, what is the simplest way to do what I want?**

Comment: I can think about a different schema for the generated tables maybe?